# Is there a filter or action to override Wordpress post_exists function for a custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using the permalink Post name in setup. I have a very large custom database where the post names are stored and would like not to create millions of posts in wp_posts. I have a custom template that gets invoked when the custom post type single- is invoked. If the post is not in wp_posts the template never gets invoked. Instead a 404 error is generated. I'd like to override wordpress in my plugin so it always thinks my custom post_type posts exist and have my template handle any missing posts, etc.

Does this make sense? I can't seem to find any info on any overrides. It seems I would want to override post_exists somehow?

Comment: This might help:  https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-intercept-404-errors-in-wordpress

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking in to template_redirect hook to see if it will work for my application.